# Found 2 versions of android-support-v7-mediarouter.jar in the dependency list when integration of chromecast

Tags: android, jar, android-support-library, chromecast

I have imported sample app for chromecast as referred from https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender But the problem occurs in CastCompanionLibrary-android-master and VideoBrowserActivity.

Also i have imported the following lib
android-support-v7-appcompat, 
android-support-v7-mediafrouter,
google-play-services_lib for this sample app.

I got this error after set up all libraries for videoBrowserActivity :

```
CastCompanionLibrary-android-master] Found 2 versions of android-support-v7-mediarouter.jar in the dependency list,
[2014-07-08 12:01:34 - CastCompanionLibrary-android-master] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[2014-07-08 12:01:34 - CastCompanionLibrary-android-master] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2014-07-08 12:01:34 - CastCompanionLibrary-android-master] Versions found are:
[2014-07-08 12:01:34 - CastCompanionLibrary-android-master] Path: E:\IW-Workspace\Siva\Android\Workspaces\2014\July\8 Jul\CastCompanionLibrary-android-master\libs\android-support-v7-mediarouter.jar
[2014-07-08 12:01:34 - CastCompanionLibrary-android-master]     Length: 168045
[2014-07-08 12:01:34 - CastCompanionLibrary-android-master]     SHA-1: 686f600c134db35397516fc208f8122c3f989893
[2014-07-08 12:01:34 - CastCompanionLibrary-android-master] Path: E:\IW-Workspace\Siva\Android\Workspaces\2014\July\8 Jul\android-support-v7-mediarouter\libs\android-support-v7-mediarouter.jar
[2014-07-08 12:01:34 - CastCompanionLibrary-android-master]     Length: 170516
[2014-07-08 12:01:34 - CastCompanionLibrary-android-master]     SHA-1: 53608747a576b6e680a6c4220f4d338a716e5599
[2014-07-08 12:01:34 - CastCompanionLibrary-android-master] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
```

i don't know what was wrong with me, Please tell me somebody how to resolve this problem.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Thanks for your response, now i am getting error in android-support-v7-appcompat.jar instead of android-support-v7-mediarouter.jar

Answer (score 1):

It means that you have two **android-support-v7-mediarouter.jar** jar files in your build path. So the solution would be to remove **android-support-v7-mediarouter.jar** from either **CastCompanionLibrary-android-master** library or from your **android-support-v7-mediarouter** library's lib folder. I usually delete the .jar file from the library and keep it in my libs folder only. Keep only one version of .jar. Then you need to fix your build path if needed. Do project->right click->properties->java build path. Tick mark all the .jar in the **order and export** tab. Then project clean.

Comment: i removed the jar file from library folder but still getting same error

Comment: now i am getting error in android-support-v7-appcompat.jar instead of android-support-v7-mediarouter.jar

Answer (score 0):

You should remove all three libraries from your own project since the CCL is already including them; just import the CCL and you should be good on that front; take a look at the CastVideos-android that uses CCL.